# Perform 2 background tasks simultaneous with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, process, background-process

**updated my question below**

I made a script where a user can import large amounts of data. After the form is submitted and the data validated I add 2 background tasks: 1 is a script that imports all the data. This script also lets the databases know how many in total and how many he has done. The second is a script that reads how much is done from the database and displays it in a nice progress bar.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "import-process.php",
    success: function(data) {}
});

var process = 0;
var checkPercentage = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get-process-status.php",
        data: "importcode=123456",
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.indexOf("ERROR") !== -1) {
                process = data;
                $("#process_balk").css('width', process + '%');
            }
        }
    });

    if (process != 100) {
        setTimeout(checkPercentage, 1000);
    } else {
        window.location.href = "import-finished.php";
    }
}

checkPercentage();
```

Both scripts, work fine. Except that the second script (getting the status of the process) isn't started after the first (importing the data) is finished. Which makes the complete thing kinda useless.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**update:**
I found out that the background process gets called only once. That's the problem. I'm just not sure how to fix it..

```
var checkPercentage = function() {
    alert("Is this function getting called every second?");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "required/get-process-status.php",
        data: "importcode=123456",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(checkPercentage, 1000);
}
```

The code above alerts "Is this function getting called every second?" every second. Like it should. However, the value 'data' is called only once. That's not what I expected.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "import-process.php",
    success: function(data) {
        checkPercentage();
    }
});

var process = 0;
var checkPercentage = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get-process-status.php",
        data: "importcode=123456",
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.indexOf("ERROR") !== -1) {
                process = data;
                $("#process_balk").css('width', process + '%');
            }
        }
    });

    if (process != 100) {
        setTimeout(checkPercentage, 1000);
    } else {
        window.location.href = "import-finished.php";
    }
}
```

I just moved checkPercantage function call from end of script to `success` function of first ajax. You can also move it to `complete` function if you wish to run it despite of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Set your callback function to be:

```
success: function(data) {
        if (!data.indexOf("ERROR") !== -1) {
            process = data;
            $("#process_balk").css('width', process + '%');
            if (process != 100) {
               setInterval(checkPercentage, 1000);
            } else {
               window.location.href = "import-finished.php";
            }
        }
    }
```

Firstly, the if statement has to be in a callback function to work the way you want it. Secondly, you should use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` because it will recheck it every interval time.

Also, yabol is right saying that the top of your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "import-process.php",
success: function(data) {
    checkPercentage();
}
});
```